# Помогите сделать массив объектов из коллекций

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

Есть HTML разметка вида

```
<article>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div><strong>Author1</strong>
    <p>desc1</p>
  </div>
  <div><strong>Author2</strong>
    <p>desc2</p>
    <p>desc2</p>
  </div>
  <div><strong>Author3</strong>
    <p>desc3</p>
    <p>desc3</p>
    <p>desc3</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Соответственно из этого нужно сделать массив объектов такого вида

```
const arr = [{title: "Title", author: "Author1", desc: ["desc1"]}, {title: "Title", author: "Author2", desc: ["desc2", "desc2"]}, {title: "Title", author: "Author3", desc: ["desc3", "desc3", "desc3"]}]
```

Я еще совсем новичок в js, перепробовал кучу вариантов но все никак не выходит. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Покажите варианты, которые вы пробовали.

Comment: Что вы пробовали? Какой результат получили? Вариантов много

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так думаю понятно будет как можно было сделать.

```js
const arr = [];

let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (const div of divs) {
  let tempObj = {};
 
  tempObj.title = document.querySelector('h3').textContent;
  tempObj.author = div.querySelector('strong').textContent;
  tempObj.desc = Array.from(div.querySelectorAll('p')).map((p) => p.textContent);
  
  arr.push(tempObj);
}

console.log('arr', arr);
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div><strong>Author1</strong>
    <p>desc1</p>
  </div>
  <div><strong>Author2</strong>
    <p>desc2</p>
    <p>desc2</p>
  </div>
  <div><strong>Author3</strong>
    <p>desc3</p>
    <p>desc3</p>
    <p>desc3</p>
  </div>
</article>
```